# Conversion of character code for a letter to a string containing the letter itself in MSVC

Tags: string, visual-c++, character, command-line-interface

MSVC 2015 CLI: I used the following code to convert the unicode for the letter A (i.e. decimal 65) into a string containing the letter itself:

```
int i = 65;
char c = (char)(i);
return c.ToString();
```

The string returned is not "A" but "65"

To resolve, I had to use the std string, i.e.

```
int i = 65;
char c = (char)(i);
std::string MyStdString = &c;
String^ d = gcnew String(MyStdString.c_str());
return d;
```

The string returned is "A"

There must be a way to solve this without the second approach. Although this solved my issue, I would be grateful for help on syntax for the first approach, and to understand why it won't work as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing between [char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/char-wchar-t-char16-t-char32-t?view=vs-2019) and [Char](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char?view=netframework-4.8)(Note Capital **C**).

Following code should give you expected result:

```
int i = 65;
Char c = i;
Console::WriteLine(c.ToString());
```